# How can I use a multi-digit number on my LineEdit?

Tags: qt

I have a numericPad that when I click on numbers button that number print on LineEdit But it's just a digit printed.
If I want to set the second digit of the first number to be deleted.
 How can I use or have a multi-digit number on my LineEdit?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you set the value of the lineedit just take the value thats already there and append the new value to the end.

```
QString current_value = ui->line_edit->text(); // lets say current value is "5"
QString new_value = "1"

ui->line_edit->setText(current_value.append(new_value));
```

Linedit now shows "51"